# Querying duplicates table into related sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a process that creates a table of duplicate records based on some arbitrary rules (details not relevant).

Every record gets checked against all other records and if a suspected duplicate is found both it and the duplicate are stored in a dupes table to be manually reviewed.

This results in a table something like this:

```
dupId,  originalId, duplicateId
1       1           2
2       1           3
3       1           4
4       2           3
5       2           4
6       3           4
7       5           6
8       5           7
9       6           7
10      8           9
```

You can see here record #1 has 3 other records it is similar to (#2,#3 and #4) and they are each similar to each other. 
Record #5 has 2 duplicates (#6 and #7) and record #8 has only 1 (#9).

I want to query the duplicates into sets, so my results would look something like this:

```
setId   recordId
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       5
2       6
2       7
3       8
3       9
```

But I am too old/slow/tired/rubbish and a bit out of my depth here.

Currently, when checking for duplicates if the record pairing is already in the table we don't insert it twice (i.e. you don't see both sides of the duplicate pairing) but can easily do so if it makes the querying simpler.

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: This has been so stripped down it is really hard to follow the details. The data just doesn't make any sense to me at all here. I can't keep track of what is what from what table and which one is who. Post some ddl, sample data and desired output. And try to make it so all the numbers are not the same in each table, or keep the names the same, so we can follow what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicates seems to be transitive, so you have all pairs.  That is, the "original" id has the information you need.

But it is not included in the duplicates and you want that.  So:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by originalid) as setid, duplicateid
from ((select originalid, duplicateid
       from t
       where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t.originalid = t2.duplicateid)
      ) union all
      (select distinct originalid, originalid
       from t
       where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t.originalid = t2.duplicateid)
      )
     ) i
order by setid;
```